# Erro no Spring com JPQL: UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data, jpql

Estou fazendo uma API REST em Spring Boot e estou com dificuldade de conseguir trazer os resultados de uma query do repository.

Eu tenho esse MER, que é uma pequena parte do meu banco:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu montei essas duas entidades no Java, o que resultou nas seguintes classes (omiti os getters, setters e imports de todas as classes a seguir pras imagens não ficarem muito grandes):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como um mesmo logradouro (isso é, uma avenida, por exemplo) pode ter vários CEPs (vide Avenida Sapopemba, Avenida Paulista etc), então a query deve me retornar o Logradouro com uma lista de LogradouroCEP (caso o mesmo Logradouro tenha mais de um CEP). Eu posso pesquisar por qualquer um dos três parâmetros: tanto pelo nomeLogradouro (da classe Logradouro) quanto pelo numeroCepLogradouro e numeroCepComplementoLogradouro (da classe LogradouroCEP).

O meu repository está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha classe de serviço está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E o meu controller está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quando rodo o projeto, ele dá o seguinte erro:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'logradouroApiController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'logradouroService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'logradouroService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'logradouroDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'logradouroDao': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.projeto.referencia.dao.LogradouroDao.findLogradouroByParameters(java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Integer)!
```

O projeto está configurado 100% certinho:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu creio que eu esteja fazendo alguma besteira na hora de retornar a lista de LogradouroCEP (que é filha do objeto Logradouro) da query. Alguém poderia me ajudar por gentileza?

Comment: Bom Dia, seus contrutores estão publicos ou privados?

Comment: Olá! Sugiro trocar as imagens por texto, pois assim as pessoas com um problema similar ao seu vão encontrar mais facilmente o problema. Utilize as ferramentas de formatação do SO para código.

Answer (score 0):

Este erro:

> Validation failed for query for method

Está dizendo que sua consulta está com a sintaxe incorreta.

O ponto onde tem um erro na sua consulta é na falta de espaço entre `?1` e o `or`. A consulta sua deve estar sendo gerada com um trecho assim: `?1or`. Colocando um espaço entre ambos provavelmente irá resolver o problema.